# Sql Server CLR Project - TFS

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

We are having trouble with a SQL CLR project in VS 2010. I checked in all changes to TFS, but when others get latest, the build is broken.

Here's what I did:

1. Created class library (`GT.Json`) in C# & built out functionality I wanted to add to CLR (requiring 3rd party libs, which is why I didn't build it directly in to CLR project)
2. Built project in #1, and registered all necessary assemblies at the SQL Server level (including 3rd party libs)
3. Added a reference to the `GT.Json` assembly now on the SQL Server

It is this reference to `GT.Json` that is breaking the build when others get latest.

Any idea how I set this up so I don't break the build?

[EDIT]
When others get latest, the reference to `GT.Json` is broken. The only solution is to remove the reference & re-add it,. I can handle this in a normal project, but this was my first edit to one of our CLR projects. On my machine, the reference I added automatically points to the /obj/sqlclr folder in the project, but that folder is not part of TFS.